# Write SESSION via function

Tags: php

I am having problem with adding items in $_SESSION variable of PHP with a custom function.
so... I want to write sessions with a function like this

```
public function set($key, $value) {
    $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
}
```

but every time when I call the function the array is overwritten

```
//$combination = "1-10"; > 1 = product_id | 10 = option_id

$this->session->set("cart", array(implode("-", $combination) => array(
    "product_id" => $combination["product_id"],
    "variant_id" => $combination["variant_id"],
    "quantity" => 1
)));
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[cart] => Array
    (
        [1-30] => Array
            (
                [product_id] => 1
                [variant_id] => 30
                [quantity] => 1
            )
    )
)
```

This is working properly

```
$_SESSION["cart"][implode("-", $combination)] = array(
    "product_id" => $combination["product_id"],
    "variant_id" => $combination["variant_id"],
    "quantity" => 1
);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[cart] => Array
(
    [1-30] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 1
            [variant_id] => 30
            [quantity] => 1
        )
    [1-29] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 1
            [variant_id] => 29
            [quantity] => 1
        )
    [1-28] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 1
            [variant_id] => 28
            [quantity] => 1
        )
)
```

Comment: `$_SESSION["cart"][implode("-", $combination)]` only adds a single array to session[cart]. How do you end up with 3 entries?

Comment: @apokryfos by adding multiple products in the cart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling set, which you have written to overwrite the entire array value.

You would either need to get it first, add your value and then set:

```
$cart  = $this->session->get("cart");
$cart[implode("-", $combination)] = array(
    "product_id" => $combination["product_id"],
    "variant_id" => $combination["variant_id"],
    "quantity" => 1
);
$this->session->set("cart", $cart);
```

or add a new method to handle a 2 dimensional array:

```
public function merge($key,$value){
    $_SESSION[$key]=array_merge($_SESSION[$key],$value);
}

$this->session->merge("cart", array(implode("-", $combination) => array(
    "product_id" => $combination["product_id"],
    "variant_id" => $combination["variant_id"],
    "quantity" => 1
)));
```

or

```
public function setInArray($key, $subKey, $value){
    $_SESSION[$key][$subKey]=$value;
}

$this->session->setInArray("cart", implode("-", $combination), array(
    "product_id" => $combination["product_id"],
    "variant_id" => $combination["variant_id"],
    "quantity" => 1
));
```

Comment: Thank you sir! That's what I wanted. Thank you!